# Restarting mysql utilizing the puppetlabs/mysql module?

Tags: mysql, puppet, vagrant

I have two folders -- one is 'public_modules' and the other is 'private_modules'. When I start a new Vagrant machine, the 'public_modules' folder is populated with modules as described in my Puppetfile (for brevity sake, these are all modules on the puppetforge). 'private_modules' holds whatever modifications and settings I need to change to the public modules. By using librarian-puppet, I don't need to check in these public modules nor rely on git submodules. Consider the following manifest file:

```
class drupaldb {
class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password => 'platform',
    override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'max_connections' => '1024', 'bind-address' => '0.0.0.0' } }
}

mysql::db { 'drupaldb':
    user     => 'root',
    password => 'platform',
    host     => '%',
    grant    => ['SELECT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE'],
}

service { 'mysql':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    subscribe => File['/etc/mysql/my.cnf']
}
}
```

Provisioning Vagrant will fail because the mysql service has already been defined in the public module here:

```
class mysql::server::service {

if $mysql::server::real_service_enabled {
    $service_ensure = 'running'
} else {
    $service_ensure = 'stopped'
}

if $mysql::server::real_service_manage {
    file { $mysql::params::log_error:
      owner => 'mysql',
      group => 'mysql',
}
service { 'mysqld':
  ensure   => $service_ensure,
  name     => $mysql::server::service_name,
  enable   => $mysql::server::real_service_enabled,
  provider => $mysql::server::service_provider,
}
}

}
```

So, what I've been unable to solve is how to instruct mysql to restart at the end of my module? I've resorted to restarting mysql via an inline shell command at the end of my Vagrantfile, but that is surely a hack.

Here is the [puppetlabs module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by added a 'restart' param to my ::mysql::server initialization.

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  override_options => $override_options,
  restart => true,
}
```

This tells the mysql module to restart mysql whenever something changes.

Answer (score 1):

What I don't understand is why do you want to restart it at all? puppetlabs-mysql module will manage all the restarts needed after all the configuration changes.

Anyway, your declaration of service wouldn't restart MySQL unless my.cnf file changes. Since all the changes are done via puppetlabs-mysql module, it will restart the service itself, so I don't see the point in your declaration.

But, not going into reasons why do you want to do it, I would suggest you to add the following resource at the end of your module:

```
notify { 'restart_mysql':
  notify  => Service['mysqld'],
  require => [ Class['::mysql::server'], ::Mysql::Db['drupaldb'] ],
}
```

Or you can do it manually with exec:

```
exec { 'restart_mysql':
  cmd     => 'service mysqld restart',
  require => [ Class['::mysql::server'], ::Mysql::Db['drupaldb'] ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the module wraps the `service` resource in a convenient class, the canonical way to approach this is to send an event to that class.

```
File['/etc/mysql/my.cnf'] ~> Class['mysql::server::service']
```

It's a little awkward, because the `file` resource isn't in local scope either. Normally it would look like this

```
file { '/etc/mysql/my.cnf':
    ...
    notify => Class['mysql::server::service']
}
```